# how to add proxy in c#

Tags: c#

i have created a application in c# i want to add proxy server how can i do it.

Comment: You want to write a proxy server? Direct a request via a proxy server?

Comment: Please define "proxy server".

Comment: I want someone else to do my work for me, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a global proxy that way

```
System.Net.Uri proxyURI = new System.Net.Uri("http://64.202.165.130:3128");
System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.Select = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxyURI);
```

Or set it for a WebRequest like this:

```
var proxyURI = new System.Net.Uri("http://64.202.165.130:3128");
var proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxyURI);

// If u need passwords:
proxy.Credentials=new NetworkCredential(username,password);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
request.Proxy = proxy;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you using webclient to access some URLs then you can use following code to set proxy for it. So that your request will tunnel through proxy server.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("proxyServer", 8080);
```